# unknown log format "combined" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Trying to set up a UDP  reverse proxy with nginx but the service cant start because I can't seem to find the right setup for the access and error logs:

this is the config file:

```
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so;
events {}
stream {
   upstream mms {
      server 192.168.7.217:2000 max_fails=10  fail_timeout=60s;
   }
   server {
      listen 192.168.7.217:6000-6010 udp;
      proxy_pass mms;
      proxy_bind $remote_addr:$remote_port transparent;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;
      error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to define a `log_format`. See the [stream log module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_log_module.html). `combined` is a predefined format for the `http` module only.

Comment: txs a lot, it worked